# Efficient algorithm for solving $\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \quad \| \mathbf{D\nabla x - b}\|^2_2$ where $\mathbf{D}$ is block-diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a block-diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ ($m > n$), $\nabla: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (assuming periodic boundary condition), and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, how to solve for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ efficiently (I mean, fast convergence and parallelizable)?

$\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \quad \| \mathbf{D\nabla x - b}\|^2_2$.

My current thought is to solve the normal equation using conjugate gradient:

$ \nabla^{\text{T}}\mathbf{D}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{D}\nabla \mathbf{x} = \nabla^{\text{T}}\mathbf{D}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{b}$.

$\mathbf{D}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{D}$ will still be a block-diagonal matrix, but $\nabla$ operator cannot be efficiently evaluated in Fourier domain any more. And the problem structure is broken.

Is there any better numerical algorithms for this special problem?

Comment: Note that methods based on conjugate gradients such as CGLS or LSQR do not require the normal equations to be available in the explicit form. Maybe you could have a look on these.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you for reply. Yes CG only needs $\mathbf{Ax}$, which numerically in my case is three simple-to-do convolutions, say cost $~6n$ in total. I would not either expect or desire to combine them into one big matrix otherwise one matrix-vector multiplication would be more costly. However, the convolutions have to be done for each CG iteration, and it slows down my application. For 100 CG iterations only $\mathbf{Ax}$ itself takes $~600n$. Whereas a FFT-based inversion takes $3n log(n) + n$ (and direct also, no need extra iterations). I would like use FFT somehow at least.

Comment: You can solve $\underset{y}{\text{min}} \ \| Dy - b\|^2_2$, and then $y = \nabla x$. As I understand $y = \nabla x$ can be solved easily. What about the modified least square problem? Can you find the QR decomposition of $D$?

Comment: @PawelKowal Thanks for the proposal. Yes both the two sub-problems are now easy to solve. But I am not sure if the solution $\mathbf{y}$ to the modified least squares problem is exactly equals ot $\nabla\mathbf{x}$. If I understand correctly, I may need to solve $\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \, \| \nabla \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|_2^2$ as the second problem, and then probably need to iterate between the above two sub-problems for a satisfactory convergence. This is highly resemble to Pg. 13 of [ADMM paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf).

Comment: @WDC As I understand, $\nabla$ is invertible, otherwise you would not be able to solve the normal equation. But in this case the solution to the second least squares problem is just $\nabla^{-1}y$.

Comment: @PawelKowal Say the true solution is $\mathbf{x}_p$. The optimal of the two problems are $\mathbf{y}^*$ and $\mathbf{x}^*$. What concerns me is, are $\mathbf{x}_p$ and $\mathbf{x}^*$ the same. Because $\mathbf{y}^*$ may probably not equal to $\nabla \mathbf{x}_p$.

Comment: @WDC If $\nabla$ is invertible, then $x^{*}\equiv \underset{x}{\text{arg}\text{min}} \ \| D\nabla x - b\|^2_2$ and $\bar{x}\equiv \nabla^{-1}\times\underset{y}{\text{arg}\text{min}} \ \| D y - b\|^2_2$ are equal.

Comment: @PawelKowal Oh yes you are right. Now I see the point. So the original problem is turivial now. Thank you. But what if $\nabla: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: @WDC Suppose, that we are going to solve the regularized least squares problem and $D$ is invertible, but $\nabla$ is not, however has full row rank. I think, that solution to this problem is equivalent to two stage least squares, where in the first state unique $y$ is found and in the second stage we solve the regularized least squares problem $\underset{x}{\text{min}} \ \|\nabla x - y\|^2_2 + \lambda\|Mx\|^2$ for some $M$. But I am not sure. These two problems seems to be strongly related.

Comment: @PawelKowal Thanks for all the helpful hints. Maybe I do need an extra $\mathbf{M}$ for regularization on $\mathbf{x}$. I need to think about it. But this two-stage optimization scheme satisfies my requirement already. Thank you again.